# Real time RTSP streaming to a React application Discussion

Tags: node.js, reactjs, video-streaming, rtsp, wowza

My company has about 200+ cameras throughout the property. I'm building a react app for analytics into some of their day to day activities and would like cameras to be played in the application. The cameras stream over RTSP.

My first solution was just to open VLC player on the host computer using a custom URL protocol for windows (This application was originally meant for managers, maybe a dozen computers). Of course requirements change, they are happy with the product and want a version for all employees. My solution is now useless. Right now we are trying to use Wowza to transcode the feeds into a more usable format, but I'm pretty sure the price tag will make them want to get rid of it soon.

I have done quite a bit of googling and found multiple solutions.

ffmpeg and openCV seem to be popular options. I'm pretty good with Python and could really build this in either one.

My question is this. Does anyone have any experience in creating these systems that could point me to information on what not to do?

My first thought is to create a server with Python and OpenCV, or Node and ffmpeg, to transcode the RTSP stream and broadcast it over http, then use React-Player to connect to that stream. I've never done this kind of thing before and am kinda just guessing at what to do.